# How to keep ~/.ssh folder secure on OS X

Tags: macos, ssh, security, encryption

My question is about storing private and public rsa keys in `~/.ssh` on OS X Yosemite.

By default `ssh-keygen` stores pairs of keys in plain text format, which means anybody who have access to my OS X account (or to unencrypted time machine volume etc) can access to my private keys. I think that this is a big lack of security.

Usually I use these keys to access github or to access digitalocean droplets.

Is there any way to keep private keys more secure (excluding full encryption of hard drive and time machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Secure your keys by using a passphrase.

```
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This will add a passphrase to an existing key created without one. You will have to enter the passphrase when you use the key, and this could (or should!) be a different password from your main user account, in case that gets compromised.

Also:

- Encrypt your OS X volume
- Encrypt your Time Machine backup

There's really no reason not to do it.

Any tampering with encrypting the folder or locking it on a filesystem level will just make it harder for you to do your actual work, which defeats the purpose of security, because you'll end up forgetting to "lock" it again.